# Question about std::function when using with static member function

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, std-function, stdbind

Why both `PassFxn(&X::StaticMemberDoIt);` and `PassFxn(std::bind(&X::StaticMemberDoIt, _1, _2, _3));` are right? Is there is an implicit conversion when invoking `PassFxn(&X::StaticMemberDoIt);` since the declaration is `void PassFxn(std::function<int(float, std::string, std::string)> func)` other than `void PassFxn(int(*func)(float, std::string, std::string))`?

What the differences between `PassFxn(&X::StaticMemberDoIt);` and `PassFxn(X::StaticMemberDoIt);`?

Here is the code snippet(https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8a0e1bb60550958) for demo:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void PassFxn(std::function<int(float, std::string, std::string)> func)
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   int result = func(12, "a", "b"); // call using function object
   std::cout << result << std::endl;
}

struct X
{
    int MemberDoIt(float f, std::string s1, std::string s2)
    {
        std::cout << "Member: " << f << ", " << s1 << ", " << s2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    static int StaticMemberDoIt(float f, std::string s1, std::string s2)
    {
        std::cout << "Static: " << f << ", " << s1 << ", " << s2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    X x;
    PassFxn(std::bind(&X::MemberDoIt, x, _1, _2, _3)); // Use a member function!

    // Or, if you have a *static* member function...
    //Why these four expression are all right?
    PassFxn(X::StaticMemberDoIt);
    
    PassFxn(&X::StaticMemberDoIt);
    
    PassFxn(std::bind(X::StaticMemberDoIt, _1, _2, _3));
    
    PassFxn(std::bind(&X::StaticMemberDoIt, _1, _2, _3)); 
    

    // ...and you can basically pass any callable object!
}
```

Comment: For regular functions (and so static method), inherited syntax from C allows both `f` and `&f` as function pointer.

Comment: Both function pointer, and result of `std::bind` are callable, and so valid argument to `std::function` (and as first argument of `std::bind`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Can I draw the conclusion that `f` is the same with `&f`?

Comment: For functions, yes.

Comment: @Jarod42 The comments for this code snippet(i.e online http://cpp.sh/9uta, quoted from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/function/) treat `f` as a function whereas `&f` as a function pointer.  It seems that there are still some differences between them.

Comment: [implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer)

Comment: Stop using std bind; I will bet dollars to donuts you don't understand the strange corner cases. Unless you do it isn't safe.  And learning them is a waste, because lambdas replace bind *and* do other things.  And people who do learn the wierd corner cases (say, well enough to implement std bind) can end up agreeing with me that you should stop using it.  Use lambdas, learn enough to mimic what you are intending to do with bind, and don't mimic the strange corner cases.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Could you please give me some examples about the aforementioned "strange corner cases"?

Comment: go to cppreference and start reading the page on std bind.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Pardon me for my ignorance. I can't see any clue after roughly reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind. Could you please give me some hints? And you see that `std::bind` belongs to the standard C++ library. So I think it's reliable.

Comment: It is reliable, but obsolete. It was added with the lambda language feature, and could do a few things it could not, in C++11.  Those few things are now gone.  Do you understand how std ref/cref and how passing bind to bind works?  How about member function pointers, overloaded functions?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  I understand member function pointers, overloaded functions, and std ref/cref. "How passing bind to bind works". If you mean how to use std::bind, the answer is yes. If you ask me how `std::bind` works behind the usage, I would say I really don't know.

Comment: Your answer grammarically makes me believe you don't.  Did you read the linked page?  Did you read "If the stored argument arg is of type T for which std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true " point?  I am not going to go further into the ways bind is surprising in a comment thread, but I will advise you against using it.  If you have further questions, read the cpp reference, then press [ask question] to add a question to SO and someone will help you (maybe me, who knows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regular functions (and so static method), inherited syntax from C allows both `f` and `&f` as function pointer.

Both function pointer, and result of `std::bind` are callable, and so valid argument to `std::function` (and as first argument of `std::bind`).

Comment: Is there is an implicit conversion when invoking `PassFxn(&X::StaticMemberDoIt);` since the declaration is `void PassFxn(std::function<int(float, std::string, std::string)> func)` other than `void PassFxn(int(*func)(float, std::string, std::string))`?

Comment: Yes, you might look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) constructor #5.